# no dash/applets shown after installing ubuntu desktop on ubuntu server 14.04 64bit

Tags: boot, server, partitioning, nautilus, uefi

I tried to install Ubuntu Server 14.04 on my server i.e:

```
  - Motherboard: mini-ITX GIGABYTE H77N-WIFI
  - Processor : Core i3
  - DDR3      : 8 GB
  - SATA HDD  : 1 x 500GB, 3 x 1TB
  - Network if: eth0,eth1,wlan0
```

This motherboard support UEFI BOOT as well as **CSM** ( Compatibility Support Module: provides legacy BIOS compatibility) wiki: [Unified Extensible Firmware Interface][1] which I **disabled** in my installation. So I configure BIOS to **boot only on UEFI mode** and boot using Ubuntu server 14.04 x64bit.iso flashdisk.

When the installer came to the point of defining partition, I choose:

```
   - guided-use entire partition
   - select disk : sda - 500GB
   - SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) - 500.1 GB ATA
            1.0 MB       FREE SPACE
     #1   536.9 MB  B  F EFIBoot
     #2   492.1 GB     F ext4       /
     #3     7.5 GB     F swap       swap
            1.1 MB       FREE SPACE
   - Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
```

Ubuntu Server 14.04 x64bit installation was without any errors, internet connection on eth0 was ok too.

after reboot and login, the screen shows :

```
no tallocstackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory
.
.
ubuntu@ubuntu:$

$ sudo apt-get update..ok
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop...ok
```

But after reboot, the screen just showed a blank ubuntu theme desktop without applets, dash or anything and then after a few moment, it shows error dialogbox :

```
" nautilus  pop up " Oops! Something went wrong." dialog. (repeat momentarily.)
---------------------------------------------
Nautilus Unable to create a required folder. Please create the following folder, or set permissions such that it can be created:
/home/user/.config/nautilus}
---------------------------------------------
```

Could it be that the desktop version was unable to locate the UEFI partition where nautilus configuration file resides ?

Because when I type :

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
```

output:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU parted.

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60001 Cylinders, total 976773168bytes
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes/4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

    Device Boot           Stat           end          Blocks         Id       System
/dev/sda1                   1          976773167    488386583+       ee        GPT
partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

when I installed ubuntu desktop over the server and enable the CSM support from mobo bios, was without any problem.

Comment: You said: "Could it be that the desktop version was unable to locate the UEFI partition where nautilus configuration file resides ? "Im no expert but shouldn't config files be located on same partition? Also,  it asked to check permissions for your home folder.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Xieerqi: I got it working!,Yeah I was thinking like that too, and after changing the permission I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

After changing the permission I got it working. Here is how I did it:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/user/.config/nautilus
```

Then

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

and after login, Voila..! Ubuntu Desktop show up with no error.

But dunno if this is the right solution to set /home/user/.config/nautilus to 777.